# Sort domains in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a list of domains and subdomains in MySQL DB as below:

```
abc.com
contactus.def.com 
pages.abc.com
help.about.abc.com
def.com
```

I want the SELECT query to sort these domains and subdomains based on domain name such that the final output is as below:

```
abc.com
pages.abc.com
help.about.abc.com
def.com
contactus.def.com
```

How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Comment: This involves a lot of string manipulation. Is it possible for you to select the results and then sort them in the c#? It would be much easier there

Comment: No i want it to be done in mysql only

Comment: @manu if you want it done only in MySql then remove the C# tag

Comment: This is a _very difficult_ problem to solve, because how much of the name constitutes the "root domain" differs.  For example `sub.example.com` and `example.com` vs `sub.example.co.uk` vs `example.co.uk`. So you can't just do something simple like strip all but the last two dot groups.

Comment: Mozilla maintains the Public Suffix List (https://publicsuffix.org/) which attempts to create a known list of possible suffixes, and there are libraries written in a number of languages to make use of the list. I doubt there is such a library of userdef functions for MySQL though.

Comment: I can get close, using an `INNER JOIN` that compares the rightmost substring to other rows in the same table, but not sorted exactly as yours is. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1a38/11 This would be better done in C#.

Comment: `select * from domains order by reverse(name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform order by from "end to start" and from "start to end" using substring_index with delimiter "." and count occurenses=2 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index such as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` order by  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fieldname`, '.', -2),SUBSTRING_INDEX(`fieldname`, '.', 2);
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac8c61/1

Answer (score 0):

substring_index(domainname,'.',-2) says search from the end forward, find the second dot and take everything after it.  This returns the domain ie. abc.com.

select domainname, substring_index(domainname,'.',-2) as a, domainname like "%.%.%" as b, domainname like "%.%.%.%" as c from db.domains order by a, b, c asc, domainname asc;

Comment: find the domain, find the count of domain names with two dots, then three dots, order by domains, then two dots, three dots and then first letter.

I learned alot of from this.  Great question.